# Codeigniter Twitter Style Stream & Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I have been searching around the web for a solution to the following and I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a web app built in Codeigniter and the main View loads in a stream of posts from a model. Currently the user has to refresh the page to get the newest content, this isn't ideal, what I would like to achieve is that the stream div updates and loads in new content periodically.

I am new to both CI and Ajax and I wondered if someone could help with a solution.

Some code…

**Model**

```
    function stream($uid, $updated, $limit) {
        $this->db->cache_on();
        $now = microtime(true);
        //$sql = "SELECT STATEMENT HERE";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($uid, $uid, $updated, $limit));

        return $query->result();
    }
```

**Controller**

```
   function index() {
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {

            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
            $data['first_name'] = $session_data['first_name'];
            $data['last_name'] = $session_data['last_name'];
            $data['avatar'] = $session_data['avatar'];
            $data['cover'] = $session_data['cover'];

            //Stream Data
            $updated = microtime(true);
            $limit = 100;
            $data['user_id'] = $session_data['id'];

            $this->load->library('pagination');

            $config['base_url'] = BASE_URL;
            $config['total_rows'] = $limit;
            $config['per_page'] = 10;
            $config['num_links'] = 20;

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            //$this->load->model('post');
            $data['results'] = $this->post->stream($data['user_id'], $updated, $limit);
            $data['notifications'] = $this->user->notifications($data['user_id']);
            $data['userStats'] = $this->user->getUserStats($data['user_id']);

            $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
            //$this->output->cache(1);
            //$this->output->enable_profiler(FALSE);
        } else {
            //If no session, redirect to login page
            redirect('/', 'refresh');
        }
    }
```

The view is complex but in essence it uses a foreach loop for the `$results` array and then places the keys in to a bootstrap div e.g

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
    <img src="<?php echo $user_avatar;?>" class="postAvatar">
    <h4><?php echo $user_full_name;?><br><small><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <?php echo $relDate.' from '.$post_location ?></small></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body bodyText">
    <div class="postBody">
          <?php echo $formatted;?>
    </div>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend you to have a look at the [WebSocket technique](http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-the-html5-websockets-api/) introduced in HTML5. It is exactly developed for such things like your newsticker.

There is also a websocket-library for crossbrowser support called [socket-io](http://socket.io/).

Maybe your are also interested in [this](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-graceful-websocket/) nice jquery plugin.

HTML5 FTW!

Comment: Is there an example out there with CI, Socket.io and MySQL?

Comment: Here you got a nice [tutorial](http://devzone.zend.com/209/writing-socket-servers-in-php/), which shows you how to use websockets with socket.io in php. Just fit it to your codeigniter datasource.

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish it, you have to do multiple things.

1. First create an api, means a function in your controller that will provide you with the latest  posts say in json format.
2. you have to use javascript/jquery to ajax that previously created api url, to fetch the latest posts, then parse the json response in javascript, after that you have to edit the html  through javascript and insert this post data in to the HTML.
3. use  setInterval to call you ajax function again and again after a particular time interval to fetch the latest post and populate them in the HTML div's